# How to include a library - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I would like to give this a try- https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema
However, I have no clue how to even get started. I literally have no idea what this means "Include the library under the following coordinates". I am new to spark and have only used it via Python/PySpark. Any pointers greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to include library in Azure Databricks

**Please follow below steps:**

- Click on computer inside bar
- Click on cluster name
- And then, click on the libraries tab and install libraries

[image: Ref1]

**Reference:**

[Install a library on a Databricks cluster | microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/cluster-libraries)

Comment: Marked this as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction. Basically I had to build a package (.jar) using something called SBT (https://www.scala-sbt.org/) and upload that. Cheers

Comment: Nice :) to know, your problem resolved